# Optional method in base class

Tags: typescript

basically I want to have a method that is optional on the base class, and the inherited classes may or not implement that method.

```
class One
{
method()
    {
        // optional
    }
}

class Two extends One
{
    // some classes don't implement it
}

class Three extends One
{
    // others do
method()
    {
        // doStuff();
    }
}
```

Then I would figure out if the method exists or not.

```
if ( object.method )
    {
    object.method();
    }
```

The idea is that the method isn't called for every object (not calling empty functions), but only when there's something defined.

I could do like this, but if there's some nicer way I'm missing..

```
class One
{
method: () => any;

constructor()
    {
    this.method = null;
    }   
}

class Two extends One
{
constructor()
    {
    super();

    this.method = this._method;
    }

_method()
    {
        // doStuff();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use *composition*. Define an *interface* which contains the method. Only certain classes implement that interface.

You can check at runtime if an object implements that interface.

Comment: I'm getting the "class defines instance member property, but extended class defines it as instance member function". Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You've made your life slightly painful by *assiging* it to `null` in the base class. If you don't do that the code becomes much simpler:

```
class One {
    method: () => any;

    constructor() {        
    }
}

class Two extends One {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    method = () => {
        // doStuff();
    }
}
```

By default it is `undefined` anyways and assigning it to `null` gives no special value.

Comment: The 'method' won't be set to the prototype this way, it will be copied for every object.

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript:

```
class One {
    method?(whatever:any):any; // optional
}

class Two extends One {
    // some classes don't implement it
}

class Three extends One {
    // others do
    method(whatever:any):any {
        // doStuff();
    }
}
```